# Two issues with displaying appointments in the fullcalender

Tags: fullcalendar

We use fullcalender 3.9.0

1. Appointments starting on Sunday or earlier and ending on Monday before 9am will not be displayed on Monday
2. For February and March 2019, no events will be displayed (events) even though the actual data is present, which has been checked.
   For 2020 this problem does not exist.

Regards
Christian

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In your case it should help to: 1) add the programming language you use and 2) the code that creates the problems.

Comment: 1. is not an issue, it's a configuration setting - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold 2. Without seeing your JSON data and your calendar setup code, we cannot possibly help you. Clearly, this is not expected behaviour, so we can't guess what you did wrong in this case. Please show us some relevant info if you would like help that consists of anything more than guesswork and speculation. Thanks.

Comment: 280/5000
I'm sorry that I may not have made all the required information.
In the documentation, I have obviously overlooked the required parameter.
The second problem I could solve in the meantime. Quotation marks in the content were the problem.
Thanks to all